# ON clicking of a span how do I change content of another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclicklistener

Let's say I have this:

```
 <div class="title">Title Example 1</div>
 <span id="test">Button</span>
```

And then on clicking of a span called #test how can I change the text in .title?

I tried using this but didn't work:

```
    $('#test').click(function(){
    $(".title").text("Haha");
    return false;
});
```

Entire HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#test').click(function(){
    $(".title").text("Haha");
    return false;
}); 
    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
             *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
             */

            $('.fancybox').fancybox();

            /*
             *  Different effects
             */

             $('.fancybox-effects-a').fancybox({
                    autoDimensions: false,
                    height: 568,
                    width: 611
                }); 

            // Change title type, overlay closing speed
            $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                helpers: {
                    title : {
                        type : 'outside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        speedOut : 0
                    }
                }
            });

            // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
            $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'over'
                    }
                }
            });

            // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
            $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
                wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
                closeClick : true,

                openEffect : 'none',

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    overlay : {
                        css : {
                            'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
            $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
                padding: 0,

                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 150,

                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                closeSpeed  : 150,

                closeClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    overlay : null
                }
            });

            /*
             *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
             */

            $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',

                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });


            /*
             *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
             */

            $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows    : false,
                nextClick : true,

                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width  : 50,
                        height : 50
                    }
                }
            });

            /*
             *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
            */
            $('.fancybox-media')
                .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
                .fancybox({
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    arrows : false,
                    helpers : {
                        media : {},
                        buttons : {}
                    }
                });

            /*
             *  Open manually
             */

            $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
            });

            $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open({
                    href : 'iframe.html',
                    type : 'iframe',
                    padding : 5
                });
            });

            $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
                $.fancybox.open([
                    {
                        href : '1_b.jpg',
                        title : 'My title'
                    }, {
                        href : '2_b.jpg',
                        title : '2nd title'
                    }, {
                        href : '3_b.jpg'
                    }
                ], {
                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width: 75,
                            height: 50
                        }
                    }
                });
            });


        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
                 <div class="title">Title Example 1</div>
 <span id="test">Button</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Works perfectly for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/B9wXY/)

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work on mine and i get no errors.  how do i debug this?

Comment: @starbucks Post us your full HTML page?

Comment: @starbucks first to check error: Open your console, `press F12 (your developer tool)` or firebug if you have.  Are you missing to refer jQuery lib?

Comment: @zenith i updated question with html

Comment: @starbucks Wrap the code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: @zenith how can i tweak this so that instead of text i can do the same thing for an entire div?

Comment: @starbucks What do you want to achieve? You want to insert a div into another?

Comment: @zenith i would simply like to change that div with another div.

Comment: @zenith can you write your comment as an aswer so i can select it.

Comment: @starbucks Don't worry about it man . I'm on my phone and too lazy to write answers from it :P You can just accept one of the answers posted. I'll try give you a comment about the div thing when I get back from work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place an "alert()" as first statement of your function and see if you get a messagebox popup?

Edit:
Try placing your Click event function within the $(document).ready(function(){}) block. I think your function never gets assigned to the click event of the html control.

Edit2:
Tested and confirmed. Your script never gets assigned to the click event handler. Either you use the inline html tag

```
<span id="test" onclick="myFunction()">button</span>
```

and then change your script to be contained in a function called myFunction

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
                $(".title").text("Haha"); //I would advise using .html here though
                return false;
        }
 </script>
```

or assign it when the page is completely loaded through JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test').click(function () {
                $(".title").text("Haha");
                return false;
            });
etc...
</script>
```

Comment: still usinh `alert()`??  Have `console.log()` messages for debugging.

Comment: If you don't generate an alert, your code code doesn't get executed. It might be that your code has crashed before the alert statement (in that case, move the alert up a level) or that your code never gets executed because it doesn't get called. I have updated my answer, try that first.

Comment: @user1671639 yea for quick debugging without any available tools, I resort to alert :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind the event handler to the element before it exists.

Move the `<script>` so it appears *after* the `<span>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try .html() instead of .text()
 And wrap your bind around a document ready since you are calling it before your html